# Dense subset of $ L_g= \left\{ f: \int g(f(x)) dx <\infty \right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let  $L_g$ define the space of all functions such that 
\begin{align}
 L_g= \left\{  f:  \int g(f(x)) dx <\infty  \right\}
\end{align}
where $g(x)$ is continiously, differentialbe and strictly convex.

Is that the set of bounded and continuous function a dense subset of $L_g$?
What other conditions do we need to impose on $g$ to have this.

Comment: By $\phi$ do you mean $g$ ? And to be in $L_g$ you probably need to look for at least continuous with *compact support* (and $g(0)=0$ to have a norm), (if you think of $g(y)=y^p$ for example) ?

Comment: @Delta-u Yes, I meant $g$.  Do you think that $g(0)=0$ is important? Can't we always redefine a new function $\hat{g}=g-g(0)$?

Comment: Look up "Orlicz spaces", for example the [references given by Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birnbaum%E2%80%93Orlicz_space). The answer is yes.

Comment: @bro Thank you for your reference. I have been looking around at several references but it is very difficult to pin down the exact condition on $g$ when this is possible.